# Does anyone know how to use Beanstalk as version control with Salesforce?

Tags: version-control

We are using Beanstalk for our WordPress application developments.  So we like to have all our business applications including Salesforce customization and codes together in one place.

Is it possible to integrate Salesforce with Beanstalk? What would the Salesforce development / release cycle looks like using Beanstalk?

Comment: Are you referring to [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)?

Comment: No, I am referring to https://beanstalkapp.com/